# Cosets of $\Bbb Z/p$ in $\Bbb Z/p^2$: do $g, 2g, 3g, \ldots, pg$ lie in separate cosets where $\langle g \rangle = \Bbb Z/p^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

Consider the short exact sequence:

$$0 \to \Bbb Z/p \to \Bbb Z/p^2 \to \Bbb Z/p \to 0$$

I'm trying to analyze the cosets of $\Bbb Z/p$ in $\Bbb Z/p^2$. If $g$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z/p^2$, is it true that $g, 2g, 3g, \ldots, pg$ lie in separate cosets? I tried out a few examples, like the case of $p = 5$ and it seems true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Yes, but it is usual to use additive notation in this example.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thanks; could you give an outline of a proof?

Comment: As presented, $\Bbb Z/p$ is not a subgroup of $\Bbb Z/p^2$. You probably mean something else.

Comment: @Lubin Oh, I meant the injection of $\Bbb Z/p$ into $\Bbb Z/p^2$ as indicated by the short exact sequence $0 \to \Bbb Z/p \to \Bbb Z/p^2 \to \Bbb Z/p \to 0$. I've updated the question.

Comment: Well, in that case, I would want you to explicitly identify the image of that injection in $\Bbb Z/p^2$.